# IBM Code Engine - Docker - 'dependency:go-offline': No such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cloud, websphere

I'm trying to get an Hello World app deploy with Code Engine.

I've spend several hours troubleshooting this with no success.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-focal

WORKDIR /app
RUN ls -la 

COPY . .
RUN ls -la
RUN chmod +x  ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

#COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

My first error message was as follows:

```
#11 [6/7] RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
#11 0.132 /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: Permission denied
#11 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c ./mvnw dependency:go-offline" did not complete successfully: exit code: 126
```

The added *chmod +x* :

```
#11 [6/7] RUN chmod +x  ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
#0 0.144 chmod: cannot access 'dependency:go-offline': No such file or directory
#11 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c chmod +x  ./mvnw dependency:go-offline" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Could anyone provide me some guidance ?

Thank you
Filipe

Comment: `RUN chmod +x mvnw` and `RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline` need to be separate commands.  Most source control systems are able to preserve file permissions, and you might double-check that the `mvnw` wrapper script is checked in as executable.

Comment: THANK YOU @DavidMaze! I was Exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved with the precious help of David.

Working solution:

```
RUN chmod +x mvnw
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
```

Thank you