# /bin/sh: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, spring, docker, maven

I'm trying to Docker build my backend but get this error

```
 => ERROR [5/8] RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline                                                                   0.5s
------
 > [5/8] RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline:
0.474 /bin/sh: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:14
--------------------
  12 |     # the pom.xml file has changed.
  13 |     RUN chmod +x mvnw
  14 | >>> RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
  15 |
  16 |     # Build the Spring Boot project
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./mvnw dependency:go-offline" did not complete successfully: exit code: 126
```

This is my DOCKERFILE

```
# Use Java as the base image
FROM openjdk:latest

# Create a working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files into the image
COPY . .

# Build all the dependencies in preparation to go offline.
RUN chmod +x mvnw
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

# Build the Spring Boot project
RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

# Copy the jar file into the image
COPY target/Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

# Start the server
CMD ["java", "-jar", "Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Is it because of the file format maybe? I am not sure but I read something about `dos2unix`

I checked this post out but still get the error

[IBM Code Engine - Docker - 'dependency:go-offline': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984380/ibm-code-engine-docker-dependencygo-offline-no-such-file-or-directory)

Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [./configure : /bin/sh^M : bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)

Comment: A Quick fix is to add a space after the `sh`

Comment: How? I am using Windows. where should I add the `sh` ?